# How to get variable out of a local function in Golang with a pointer value?

Tags: function, variables, go, scope, aws-sdk-go

Sorry I am pretty new to **golang**.  I am struggling to understand the scope of variables.  I tried to create a global variable to grab the variable out of the local function, however I keep getting an error that it has not been declared. I also tried to do a return statement, however I keep getting a syntax error of not having enough arguments and no return values.
I added something like

```
func main() string { return Test2 }
```

But I am doing something wrong, can't get my head around this issue

I tried creating a global variable to store the value outside the local function.  I also tried to create a return function to grab the variable.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
)

var Test2 string

func main() {
    sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )
    svc := dynamodb.New(sess)
    input := &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
        Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "id": {
                S: aws.String("ami-xxxxx"),
            },
        },
        TableName: aws.String("table"),
    }

    result, _ := svc.GetItem(input)
    Test := result.Item["id"].S
    Test2 := *Test
    fmt.Println(Test2)

}

fmt.Println(Test2)
```

> syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body

Comment: Two issues: one, as the compile error says, you've got a `fmt.Println` outside of any function; and two, where you have `Test2 := *Test`, that is creating a new local variable `Test2` that shadows the package variable of the same name. Most basic questions are answered within the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) which only takes a few minutes to finish.

Comment: So the var Test2 string is not considered the same variable as the one inside the local function.  I thought I was passing the global variable in the local function.

Comment: If you want to assign to the package variable `Test2`, use `Test2 = *Test`. If you use `:=` it creates a new local variable.